# Unit testing network bound resource

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I'm aware that there are a couple of topics on this but none of them solve my issue.

I'm trying to test an implementation of NetworkBoundResource.

```
inline fun <ResultType, RequestType, ErrorType> networkBoundResource(
    crossinline query: () -> Flow<ResultType>,
    crossinline fetch: suspend () -> Response<RequestType>,
    crossinline saveFetchResult: suspend (RequestType) -> Unit,
    crossinline onFetchFailed: (Response<*>?, Throwable?) -> ErrorType? = { _, _ -> null },
    crossinline shouldFetch: (ResultType) -> Boolean = { true },
    coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) = flow<Resource<ResultType, ErrorType>> {
    val data = query().first()
    emit(Resource.Success(data))

    if (shouldFetch(data)) {
        val fetchResponse = safeApiCall { fetch() }
        val fetchBody = fetchResponse.body()
        if (fetchBody != null) {
            saveFetchResult(fetchBody)
        }

        if (!fetchResponse.isSuccessful) {
            emit(Resource.Error(onFetchFailed(fetchResponse, null)))
        } else {
            query().map { emit(Resource.Success(it)) }
        }
    }
}.catch { throwable ->
    emit(Resource.Error(onFetchFailed(null, throwable)))
}.flowOn(coroutineDispatcher)
```

This works as expected in my use case in production code.

```
override suspend fun getCategories() = networkBoundResource(
    query = {
        categoryDao.getAllAsFlow().map { categoryMapper.categoryListFromDataObjectList(it) }
    },
    fetch = {
        categoryServices.getCategories()
    },
    onFetchFailed = { errorResponse, _ ->
        categoryMapper.toError(errorResponse)
    },
    saveFetchResult = { response ->
        // Clear the old items and add the new ones
        categoryDao.clearAll()
        categoryDao.insertAll(categoryMapper.toDataObjectList(response.data))
    },
    coroutineDispatcher = dispatchProvider.IO
)
```

I have my test setup like this (using turbine for flow testing).

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class NetworkBoundResourceTests {

    data class ResultType(val data: String)
    sealed class RequestType {
        object Default : RequestType()
    }

    sealed class ErrorType {
        object Default : RequestType()
    }

    private val dispatchProvider = TestDispatchProviderImpl()

    @Test
    fun `Test`() = runTest {
        val resource = networkBoundResource(
            query = { flowOf(ResultType(data = "")) },
            fetch = { Response.success(RequestType.Default) },
            saveFetchResult = { },
            onFetchFailed = { _, _ -> ErrorType.Default },
            coroutineDispatcher = dispatchProvider.IO
        )

        resource.test {
           
        }
    }
}
```

The coroutine dispatcher is set to unconfined through DI/Test dispatcher.

I want to test that;

Emitting first data from query, then query is updated and new data from saveFetchResult then `query().map { emit(Resource.Success(it)) }` emits the updated data from that save result.

I think I need to do something around a spyk on my flow with MockK but I can't seem to figure it out. `query()` will always return the same flow of data as it's mocked to do so if I `awaitItem()` again it returns the same data (as it should) as that's what the mock is setup for.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to test this. Not exactly how I imagined it in my head.

```
@Test
fun `Given should fetch is true and fetch throws exception, When retrieving data, Then cached items emitted and error item after`() =
    runTest {
        val saveFetchResultAction = mockk<(() -> Unit)>("Save results action")
        val fetchErrorAction = mockk<(() -> ErrorType)>("Fetch error action")
        every { fetchErrorAction() } answers { ErrorType }

        val fetchRequestAction = mockk<(() -> Response<RequestType>)>("Fetch request action")
        coEvery { fetchRequestAction() } throws (Exception(""))

        networkBoundResource(
            query = { flowOf(ResultType) },
            fetch = { fetchRequestAction() },
            saveFetchResult = { saveFetchResultAction() },
            onFetchFailed = { _, _ -> fetchErrorAction() },
            shouldFetch = { true },
            coroutineDispatcher = dispatchProvider.IO
        ).test {

            // Assert that we've got the cached item
            val cacheItem = awaitItem()
            assertThat(cacheItem).isInstanceOf(Resource.Success::class.java)

            val errorItem = awaitItem()
            assertThat(errorItem).isInstanceOf(Resource.Error::class.java)
            awaitComplete()
            
            // Verify order & calls
            verifyOrder {
                fetchRequestAction()
                fetchErrorAction()
            }

            verify(exactly = 1) { fetchErrorAction() }
            verify(exactly = 1) { fetchRequestAction() }
            verify(exactly = 0) { saveFetchResultAction() }
        }
    }
```